# Using random.choice() in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, list, random, seq

I am getting an error when I try to assign a random vertex from 3 possible vertices to a variable c.

```
#Establish locations for the 3 vertices
vertex1 = (0,0)
vertex2 = (canv_width,0)
vertex3 = (canv_width//2,canv_height)
c = random.choice(vertex1,vertex2,vertex3)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: choice() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Online someone said to try and wrap the sequence of choices in a list. So i tried:

```
c = random.choice[vertex1,vertex2,vertex2]
```

error:

```
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the elements in an iterable, yes, but then you need to call the function using parenthesis; in your second example you omitted these parenthesis and that is the cause of your second error.

Try this:

```
c = random.choice([vertex1, vertex2, vertex2])
```

which is the same as creating a list with all the possible selections:

```
my_options = [vertex1, vertex2, vertex2]  # a simple list with elements
c = random.choice(my_options)             # this selects one element from the list
```

Docs for [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice).

Answer (score 0):

> someone said to try and wrap the sequence of choices in a list

They were right. But you're not supposed to replace the parentheses with square ones.

You want to pass a list as an argument to the function random.choice().

```
c = random.choice([vertex1,vertex2,vertex2])
```

It creates a new list, containing your vertices, and passes it as an argument to random.choice(), equivalent to this:

```
choices = [vertex1, vertex2, vertex3]
c = random.choice(choices)
```